# How to replace characters in a regex

Tags: regex, replace

I have a function that takes a string and checks that it contains a valid list of zip codes:

```
function ValidateZipCodeString(listOfZipCodes) {
    // Only 5-digit zip codes are allowed
    //  Zip codes can be separated by a comma, a space, or both
    //  Any other characters will cause the error label to display
    var regex = /^\d{5}(\s*,\s*\d{5})*$/;
    return regex.test(listOfZipCodes);
}
```

A "valid" string of zip codes can be

```
12345,67854
OR
12345 35647, 09873

BUT NOT

1234565
OR
asd45, 12346
```

This works fine as is - as far as validating that the string is okay. What I need to have it do now, is anywhere there is only a comma OR a space, have both a comma AND a space. So using the above examples, I'd get

```
12345, 67854
OR
12345, 35647, 09873
```

How can I do that?

**[Clarifying Info]**

I need to clarify my intentions as far as making changes to the existing function. As I said, it works fine, and I just need the function to pass back a boolean to tell the calling function whether to display a warning label or not.

I need to add to the functionality of the ValidateZipCodeString function such that, when a *valid* list of zip codes is in the string, I want to modify that string (make sure comma *and* string are between each five-digit zip code) and then write that string to the text box that the string of zip codes came from.

Comment: Is `12345,,,,67890` valid?

Comment: @M42, Good question! There are two valid zip codes in there. I'll say "yes" but anything beyond a single comma and a single space needs to be removed/replaced

Answer (score 0):

Instead of \s* you can use character class of coma and whitespace

```
var regex = /^\d{5}([\s,]*\d{5})*$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with two functions:

```
s="12345,ad7854"
t="12345 35647, 09873"
function ReformatZipCodeArray(arrayOfZipCodes) {
    // Only 5-digit zip codes are allowed
    //  Zip codes can be separated by a comma, a space, or both
    //  Any other characters will cause the error label to display
    if (arrayOfZipCodes == null) {
        return null;
    }
    var regex = /^\d{5}$/;
    var areZipsInArrayValid = true;
    var invalidZips = [];
    arrayOfZipCodes.map(function(possibleZipCode) {
        if (regex.test(possibleZipCode) == false) {
            areZipsInArrayValid = false;
            invalidZips.push(possibleZipCode);
        }
    });
    if (areZipsInArrayValid) {
        return arrayOfZipCodes.join(", ");
    } else {
        console.log("ERROR: invalid zips are ", invalidZips);
        return null;
    }
}

function split(listOfZipCodes) {
    // Split by either a space or a comma or any combination of those
    if (listOfZipCodes.trim().length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    var regex = /[\s,]+/;
    return listOfZipCodes.split(regex);
}

console.log(ReformatZipCodeArray(split(s)))
```

The output of the above code will look like this:

```
ERROR: invalid zips are  ["ad7854"]
```

The output of the valid string of zips ("12345 35647, 09873") looks like this:

```
12345, 35647, 09873
```

Comment: I see how this is supposed to work, but I'm not quite sure how exactly to use it in my code. The ValidateZipCodeString() is called when a form's submit button is clicked. If the function returns false, the warning label displays. I don't need to pass anything back to the caller other than whether the string is valid or not. I should have included this in my question (and I will add it), but upon detecting a valid list of zip codes (5-digits separated by commas and/or spaces), I want to modify the contents of the text box itself from there, still only passing a boolean to the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
function ValidateZipCodeString(listOfZipCodes) {
    // Only 5-digit zip codes are allowed
    //  Zip codes can be separated by a comma, a space, or both
    //  Any other characters will cause the error label to display
    var regex = /^\d{5}(?:[\s,]+\d{5})*$/;
    see the change here __^^^^^^
    return regex.test(listOfZipCodes);
}
```

**regex explain:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^\d{5}(?:[\s,]+\d{5})*$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{5}                    digits (0-9) (5 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s,]+                   any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), ',' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{5}                    digits (0-9) (5 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I plugged your change into my code and it didn't have any affect. The validation still works, but when I entered this string: "12335,21342 21343" a space didn't get inserted after the comma and a comma didn't get inserted before the space (respectively).